How would your code look in tex-core?
Ok, I try again:
Please put in a self chosen short code snippet of a modern Latex code and try to show, if and how it is possible, to get the same result in TeX-Core. If you cannot do this, just leave the question to others.
Try to show, that you are able to follow rules: No comments, no sophistry,  just answers.
